# Why is octave package not showing up in apt search?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, chroot, octave

I'm using 'termux'(android terminal emulator ). I've recently installed Ubuntu inside it in a 'proot' environment. When I searched for octave package using 'apt search octave' , I can't find any result. Then I manually searched for octave in Ubuntu packages to verify whether it is available for 'armhf'. To my surprise it is available for 'armhf' . I'm really dying to use octave on my android . Why is it not showing up in apt search ? What can I do to fix it? [image: my architecture info]

Ubuntu package search:https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=Octave

Output of "cat /etc/apt/sources.list"

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security main restricted
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful-security multiverse
```

Comment: You should enable `universe` on your `sources.list`

Comment: what repos do you have? show us what is in `/etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`octave`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/octave) package is available on the `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install octave
```

[Download Page for octave](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/armhf/octave/download):

> You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` like this:

```
deb http:// artful main universe
```

For your case just do this:
Change the 3rd line to :

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful main universe restricted
```

then update your system.

Comment: "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful main restricted" and "deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful universe" is already there. is there something more to add ?

Comment: @AbinashDash Change the 3rd line to `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ artful main universe restricted
` then update your system.

Comment: Now i can access all packages... very very  thank u... I'm just curious why it was not working though 'universe' was there in 14th line of 'sources.list'?

Comment: @AbinashDash package `octave` is available on the `universe` repository but it have some dependencies on the `main` repository.